# Ubuntu 12.04.3 End of Support

Tags: 12.04, support

I have a pc for working with 12.04.3, I've read that it will lost support, do I need to install 14.04.1?

I would like to use 12.04 until 2017, it works great and as we use it for working I would'n want to have the risk of installing another version.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to update to 14.04, Ubuntu 12.04 will [be supported until 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Technically, 12.04.**3** is no longer supported, since it has (since February) been superseded by 12.04.**4**. That's nothing to worry about, since that last digit just signifies the service release, which (basically) only matters when installing a new system. Any currently installed Ubuntu 12.04 with all the latest updates automatically is a 12.04.4.

Comment: But kernel versions are not the same,are they? I think maybe the kernel versions for example of 12.04.3 will not be updated anymore...

Comment: An updated 12.04.3 is the same as 12.04.4, kernel included. I don't know where you get that idea, but there is nothing special in kernels in point releases. They are just upgraded install media to avoid downloading tons of updates.

Comment: I thought that 12.04 and 12.04.1 had the kernel of 12.04, 12.04.2 the kernel of 12.10,13.04.3 13.04 one and so... If you read in Spanish here is the link http://libuntu.com/canonical-anuncia-que-pronto-las-versiones-12-04-2-12-04-3-y-12-04-4-se-quedaran-sin-soporte/

Comment: There's multiple kernels available for 12.04, you can choose which ones to install by installing the respective meta-packages, like `linux-generic-lts-trusty` for the 14.04 kernel. Here's some [more information on the LTS stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).